# How can i prevent these out of range exceptions, "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array"?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, arrays

First of all, TamerData is attached to a new byte array as you will see stated in the function, within the lobby class. Now the troubling area is that in the error log it shows that line 260 is incorrect, which is "qry.Add("maxHP", TamerData[charModel - 80001][3]);".
Now TamerData is a byte array as i've said. Another error that is being recieved is, "CreateChar Ikuto Frosty Error: CreateCharacter()" <--- Main error being dealt with. This function is shown in the source code.

**Line of Error**

```
qry.Add("maxHP", TamerData[charModel - 80001][3]);
```

**--Database-lobby.cs**

```
public static byte[][] TamerData = new byte[][] { new byte[] { 10, 2, 90, 80 }, new byte[] { 8, 1, 100, 90 }, new byte[] { 8, 1, 90, 100 } };

public static int CreateCharacter(uint AcctId, int pos, int charModel, string charName, int digiModel)
        {
            int charId = -1;
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection con = Connect())
                {
                    Query qry = new Query(Query.QueryMode.INSERT, "chars");
                    qry.Add("charName", charName);
                    qry.Add("charModel", charModel);
                    qry.Add("accountId", AcctId);

                    qry.Add("inventory", new ItemList(63).Serialize());
                    qry.Add("storage", new ItemList(70).Serialize());
                    qry.Add("equipment", new ItemList(27).Serialize());
                    qry.Add("quests", new QuestList().Serialize());

                    qry.Add("maxHP", TamerData[charModel - 80001][3]);
                    qry.Add("maxDS", TamerData[charModel - 80001][2]);
                    qry.Add("HP", TamerData[charModel - 80001][1]);
                    qry.Add("DS", TamerData[charModel - 80001][2]);
                    qry.Add("AT", TamerData[charModel - 80001][0]);
                    qry.Add("DE", TamerData[charModel - 80001][1]);

                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = qry.GetCommand(con))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

**Error log below**

> [MapDB] Loaded 35 maps. [DigimonDB] Loaded 256 digimon. This server is
>   configured to route players to the game server at 37.157.245.26:7000
>   ServerInfo found... Listening... Accepting a client:
>   151.226.122.217:62189 Accepted connection: 151.226.122.217:62189 CreateChar Ikuto Frosty Error: CreateCharacter()
>   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.    at Digital_World.SqlDB.CreateCharacter(UInt32 AcctId, Int32
>   pos, Int32 charModel, String charName, Int32 digiModel) in
>   C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master
>   Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\DigitalWorld\Database
>   - Lobby.cs:line 261 Error: CreateDigimon() MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Out of range value
>   for column 'characterId' at row 1    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int32& insertedId)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32
>   statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
>   at Digital_World.SqlDB.CreateMercenary(UInt32 charId, String digiName,
>   Int32 digiModel, Int32 digiScale, Int32 digiSize, Int32 intimacy) in
>   C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master
>   Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\DigitalWorld\Database
>   - Game.cs:line 410 System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at Digital_World.SqlDB.GetTamerPosition(UInt32 acctId, Int32
>   slot) in C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master
>   Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\DigitalWorld\Database
>   - Lobby.cs:line 200 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Server stack trace:     at Digital_World.PacketLogic.Process(Client
>   client, Byte[] buffer, Settings Opt) in C:\Users\Digimon
>   Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master
>   Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\Lobby
>   Server\PacketLogic.cs:line 106    at
>   Digital_World.LobbyMainWin.PacketProcessor(Client client, Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 length) in C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon
>   Master Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\Lobby
>   Server\DigitalWorldLobby.xaml.cs:line 60    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)    at
>   Digital_World.Network.SocketWrapper.dlgRead.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Digital_World.Network.SocketWrapper.ProcessedRead(IAsyncResult ar) in
>   C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master
>   Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\DigitalWorld\Network\Socket.cs:line
>   235

Thank you for any help that is given, sorry if my question isnt very specific or relevant to any other user, this has just been very troubling.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question contains so much source code that most people won't look it over.  With respect, I suggest you edit your question to reduce it to the few lines of code causing the out-of-bounds exception.  And be happy you're working in C#, not C.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, sorry for the misconception. The post has been edited.